# How to optimize and find minimum from the two sql query, by writing it as single query?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I have two queries. How can I write them into a single query for efficient performance? I need the minimum value of the result of `$sql1` and `$sql2`. Is it possible?

```
$sql1="SELECT sum(pv_value) as pv FROM `{$wpdb->prefix}wpmlm_pv_meta` as M WHERE pv_meta like 'left_%' and user_id={$user_id}";
$sql2="SELECT sum(pv_value) as pv FROM `{$wpdb->prefix}wpmlm_pv_meta` as M WHERE pv_meta like 'right_%' and user_id={$user_id}";
```

Comment: Does your question involve WordPress? What other interface and/or programming languages are involved? Could you elaborate a bit? Adding the DDL for the table structure would be helpful. And adding some sample data would also assist in answering your question.

Comment: This query for WordPress custom plugin development.  ( Woo-Commerce Multi Level Marketing System add on )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a CTE with a group-by to generate two sums and then take the min.

```
$sql="

  with cte as (
    select sum(pv_value) as s FROM `{$wpdb->prefix}wpmlm_pv_meta` as M
    WHERE ( pv_meta like 'left_%' or pv_meta like 'right_%' )  
    and user_id={$user_id} 
    group by pv_meta like 'right_%'
  )
  select min(s) from cte ;
 ";
```

Answer (score 0):

From MySQL 8.0, you can use [`WITH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) to first filter for `user_id`:

```
WITH Raw AS (
  SELECT pv_value, pv_meta
  FROM `{$wpdb->prefix}wpmlm_pv_meta`
  WHERE user_id={$user_id}
), Raw2 AS (
  SELECT
    SUM(
      CASE WHEN pv_meta LIKE 'left_%' THEN pv_value ELSE 0 END
    ) AS leftSum,
    SUM(
      CASE WHEN pv_meta LIKE 'right_%' THEN pv_value ELSE 0 END
    ) AS rightSum
  FROM Raw
)
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN leftSum < rightSum THEN rightSum
    ELSE leftSum
  END
FROM Raw2
```

assuming that the external parameters are the same in the queries.

Your original query (queries) used two WHERE-conditions: one for filtering for the `user_id`, and one for a `LIKE` prefix search. The best working of the MySQL would be if it would first filter first for the `user_id` by an index, and then it would use a linear scan for the `LIKE`. However, there is no guarantee for it to do. It is possible, and even likely, that your query triggers a linear scan *on the whole table*.

This optimization not only reduces the required two searches to a single one, but it also *enforces* to commit the `user_id` scan first.

If you don't have an index of `wpmlm_pv_meta(user_id)` then create it.

Answer (score 0):

The performance issue is more likely to be in indexing than in one versus two queries.

The `meta` table needs `INDEX(user_id, pv_meta)` in that order.  (I should be better than simply `(user_id)`.)

More on improving WP's `postmeta`:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta